# Displaying text pyramid from topographic view

Tags: c, algorithm

I write in C on arduino uno. The idea is to display pyramid from topographic view so variables that I have is the 'seedP' - middle value, the size of pyramid 'sizeP' - the amount of layers and how many letters are in a row - 'layer'.

The pyramid with those values in the code seedP = 6, sizeP = 3 would look like:

```
44444
45554
45654
45554
44444
```

Here is the code:

```
void setup()
   {
     Serial.begin(9600);
     int seedP = 6; //Centre value
     int sizeP = 3; //Amount of layers
     int layer = (sizeP*2)-1;

     for(int i=0; i<layer; i++){
       for(int j=0; j<layer; j++){
           Serial.print(seedP);
       }
       Serial.println();
     }
   }
```

I still cannot fully grasp the concept of the algorithm I could potentially check for first and last layer then display a value full of '4' in this example but I'm not sure how to deal with other layers. The code right now displays only '6'es in 5 columns and 5 in a row.

Edit: Updated code and below is the grid

```
void setup()
   {
     Serial.begin(9600);

     int sizeP = 3; //Amount of layers
     int layer = (sizeP*2)-1;

     int seedP = 6; //Centre value
     int seedX = sizeP-1;
     int seedY = sizeP-1;

     for(int i=0; i<layer; i++){
       for(int j=0; j<layer; j++){
           //i,j = x,y grid
           int distanceX, distanceY, distance; //Distance between a cell and center value
           distanceX = abs(seedX - j);
           distanceY = abs(seedY - i);
           distance = distanceX + distanceY;
       }
       Serial.println();
     }
   }
```

Values from each cell to the center

```
(0,0)=4, (0,1)=3,   (0,2)=2,  (0,3)=3,  (0,4)=4
(1,0)=3, (1,1)=2,   (1,2)=1,  (1,3)=2,  (1,4)=3
(2,0)=2, (2,1)=1,   (2,2)=0,  (2,3)=1,  (2,4)=2
(3,0)=3, (3,1)=2,   (3,2)=1,  (3,3)=2,  (3,4)=3
(4,0)=4, (4,1)=3,   (4,2)=2,  (4,3)=3,  (4,4)=4
```

Comment: When you use `Serial.print(seedP);` without ever updating `seedP` how can you expect that a different value than 6, the value you initialized seedP with, will be printed?

Comment: @flowit I don't expect different value I'm looking for guidance because I know what the code is supposed to do as I described it I just don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: Your loop indices span a grid (0,0) to (layer-1,layer-1). You can calculate the distance from any point in this grid to its center. Depending on the distance you have to print a different value. If you choose a clever distance metric you can use a simple subtraction to calaculate the value you have to print.

Comment: Indeed, the desired metric is the so-called [Manhattan distance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) to the center.

Comment: @flowit I do have distances but I'm not sure how to properly use them now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice puzzle, here is my suggestion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* get the depth relative to the pyramids center, which is at origo */
int depth(int x, int y)
{
    x = abs(x);
    y = abs(y);

    return x > y ? x : y;
}

/* walk from (-(size - 1), size - 1) along the x and y axis, and print
 * the center value minus the current depth */
void pyramid(char center, int size)
{
    int x, y;

    size--;

    for (x = -size; x <= size; x++) {
        for (y = -size; y <= size; y++)
            putchar(center - depth(x, y));
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char seedP = argv[1][0];
    int sizeP = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);

    pyramid(seedP, sizeP);
}
```

Note that there is *no* error handling of any kind here, you'd better run it with two arguments.

Example:

```
$ gcc pyramid.c -o pyramid && ./pyramid 6 7
0000000000000
0111111111110
0122222222210
0123333333210
0123444443210
0123455543210
0123456543210
0123455543210
0123444443210
0123333333210
0122222222210
0111111111110
0000000000000
```

Comment: thank you very much for the solution, I almost got there myself I do have the values for distance between the middle value and other cells now I need to somehow use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with a serial output I suggest the implementation of a "frame buffer" object.

The pyramid (a square within the previous square) is written to the "frame buffer".

And finally, the "frame buffer" could be serialized to the serial port or to the text terminal.

Check out my suggestion:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct frame_buffer_s
{
    int ncols;
    int nrows;
    char ** buf;
} frame_buffer_t;


void frame_buffer_destroy( frame_buffer_t * frm )
{
    int i = 0;

    if( frm->buf )
    {
        for( i = 0; i < frm->nrows; i++ )
            if( frm->buf[i] )
                free( frm->buf[i] );

        free( frm->buf );
    }

    free( frm );
}


frame_buffer_t * frame_buffer_create( int ncols, int nrows )
{
    frame_buffer_t * frm = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    frm = (frame_buffer_t*) calloc( 1, sizeof(frame_buffer_t) );

    if( !frm )
        return NULL;

    frm->ncols = ncols;
    frm->nrows = nrows;

    frm->buf = (char**) calloc( nrows, sizeof(char*) );

    if( !frm->buf )
    {
        frame_buffer_destroy( frm );
        return NULL;
    }

    for( i = 0; i < nrows; i++ )
    {
        frm->buf[i] = (char*) calloc( ncols, sizeof(char) );

        if( !frm->buf[i] )
        {
            frame_buffer_destroy( frm );
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return frm;
}


void frame_buffer_draw_square( frame_buffer_t * this, int row, int col, int size, char ch )
{
    int i = 0;

    size--;

    for( i = 0; i <= size; i++ )
    {
        this->buf[col + i][row] = ch;
        this->buf[col + i][row+size] = ch;
        this->buf[col][row + i] = ch;
        this->buf[col + size][row + i] = ch;
    }
}


void frame_buffer_draw_pyramid( frame_buffer_t * frm, int col, int row, int size, char seed )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 1; i <= size; i++ )
        frame_buffer_draw_square( frm, row + size - i, col + size - i, (i * 2) - 1, seed-- );
}


void frame_buffer_render_terminal( frame_buffer_t * frm )
{
    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;

    for( row = 0; row < frm->nrows; row++ )
    {
        for( col = 0; col < frm->ncols; col++ )
        {
            char ch = frm->buf[col][row];

            printf( "%c", (ch)?ch:' ' );
        }

        printf( "\n" );
    }
}


void frame_buffer_send_serial( frame_buffer_t * frm )
{
    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;

    /* Serial.begin(9600); */

    for( row = 0; row < frm->nrows; row++ )
    {
        for( col = 0; col < frm->ncols; col++ )
        {
            char ch = frm->buf[col][row];

            /* Serial.print( (ch)?ch:' ' ); */
        }

        /* Serial.println(); */
    }
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    frame_buffer_t * frm = NULL;

    /* Read command line arguments */
    char seed = argv[1][0];
    int size = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);

    /* Create a 20x20 frame buffer */
    frm = frame_buffer_create( 20, 20 );

    /* Draw Pyramid in the frame buffer */
    frame_buffer_draw_pyramid( frm, 0, 0, size, seed );

    /* Write our frame buffer to terminal */
    frame_buffer_render_terminal( frm );

    /* Write our frame buffer to serial output */
    frame_buffer_send_serial( frm );

    /* Destroy frame buffer */
    frame_buffer_destroy( frm );

    return 0;
}

/* eof */
```

Example:

```
$ ./pyramid 9 10
0000000000000000000 
0111111111111111110 
0122222222222222210 
0123333333333333210 
0123444444444443210 
0123455555555543210 
0123456666666543210 
0123456777776543210 
0123456788876543210 
0123456789876543210 
0123456788876543210 
0123456777776543210 
0123456666666543210 
0123455555555543210 
0123444444444443210 
0123333333333333210 
0122222222222222210 
0111111111111111110 
0000000000000000000 

$ ./pyramid E 5
AAAAAAAAA           
ABBBBBBBA           
ABCCCCCBA           
ABCDDDCBA           
ABCDEDCBA           
ABCDDDCBA           
ABCCCCCBA           
ABBBBBBBA           
AAAAAAAAA
```

Hope it Helps!